# Hiding and showing rows according to conditions but without using if-else in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a Viewcontroller,lets say ViewcontrollerA. On that ViewController there is tableview...&tableview has custom cells which has ten rows.Now,I have two conditions...In condition One,I want to show only 7 rows,hiding 3 rows and then adjusting the screen automatically(i.e.proper spaces between textfields on row ,proper height & width of textfields etc.).On the other hand,In condition two,I want to show all the ten rows having textfields with proper constraints and spaces.

I know I can do it using If-else condition but I don't want to use if else condition as there are number of scenarios where this thing is need to be implemented and using so many if-else would be cumbersome.

It would be great if anyone could suggest any framework or library to achieve this thing.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of my knowledge there is no frame work for that. If number of conditions are more then use switch case. When compared with if-else it is better.

Comment: No,switch also i don't want to use ....I have gone through few questions realted to this and have got these two links as help https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm#make-a-row-or-section-invisible-depending-on-other-rows-values
https://github.com/kxzen/KXJsonUI_ios but couldn't implement it in my project.

Comment: You can use UIStackView, with one if-else you can hide textfields and UIStackView will manage proper spacing among visible items.

Comment: Is table view cells are static or dynamic?

Comment: cells are dynamic

Comment: @Surjeet...but how would it work for dynamic tableviewcells?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable for row height and return it in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Calculate the cell height in `viewDidAppear` and reload the tableView.

like: `CGFloat cellHeight = tableView.frame.size.height / numberOfRows;`

To have proper space, Set constraints for your text fields and other components of the cell. Then by setting the cell height with the global variable you created, cells will have proper width, height and spacing you need.

Hope this would help you..